# Android Studio: Can't resolve imports (android.support.*)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, android-support-library

AndroidStudio is driving me crazy again...
I got a one year old AS project (that worked just fine) from my Win 7 PC and want to add stuff to it on my Win 10 workstation but even though AS says that the build completed successfully, it won't resolve a couple of imports, which leads to loads of red squiggly lines:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

- Android Studio: 2.1.3
- Build tools: 25.0.2 (was installed before installing AS), 23.0.3 (installed
  after first errors), 27.0.3 (installed after the other 2)
- APIs: 19, 21, 23, 24
- Android Support Repository 47

Yes, there's an entry for Maven in the "build.gradle" file that is directly in the project folder.

The "app" gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'
}
```

The first "compile" has a squiggly line too and the message says:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). 
Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 23.4.0.
```

If I use "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'" the build fails at ":app:processDebugResources" and it complains:

```
AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

The logs begin with:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

What exactly does AS want (apart from getting on my nerves)?

Comment: "alphas" are often problematic, try with `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'`
You can Upgrade AS to v3, It resolved most of issues with repositories for me...

Comment: With the alpha the build failed completely, while it was successful with v7 23.+. There's no version 27.0.3 in my project (only the 3 I mentioned above) and I have to idea where to even get it. No idea why it won't work at all because it did just fine on my Win 7 PC, even though I remember AS being an idiot quite often. v3? I downloaded AS today, about 3-4 hours ago (that's how long I've been trying to get it to work...), so I should have the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried "Invalidate Caches/ restart" in Android Studio??
I have also faced issues like this, which was solved by this.

Comment: I just did and now the "v4" imports actually seem to work (normal cleans/rebuilds didn't help) - so thanks for that - but the two "v7" ones still can't be resolved, even though nothing's underlined in the gradle file anymore (with v7 23 and v3 23.0.3).

Answer (score 2):

Clear your cache and do a `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` at the root of your project.

Saved my ass pretty often.

Comment: Use a term if you are on a unix system or cmd if your are on windows. At the root of each android project, you have a binary named "gradlew". It is the gradle wrapper. Run it with the option "--refresh-dependencies".

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.3'
```

remove above line and sync project : File > Sync project with gradle files

Comment: After doing what duke suggested, your suggestion didn't change anything - neither for the better nor for the worse. The "v7" imports still can't be resolved after cleaning/rebuilding the project.

Comment: then restart your studio with invalidate cache. And for batter performance buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" should be match with compileSdkVersion

Comment: I just did and it's amazing, now it actually recognizes both the v4 and the v7 imports and even though I haven't fully run it yet, there are no error messages atm  - thanks! I don't own any phones with Android 8.1, so I have to keep the compiledSdkVersion and the targetSdkVersion at 23. I'd love to use buildToolsVersion 23.0.3 (that's what it was set to originally) but then AS whines that the minimum supported version for the Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2 is 27.0.3.